# Add New Select Option for Product Custom Options

Tags: javascript, custom-options

I have a case which trying to add 'radio_date' option (under Select option group) for input type in adminhtml product custom options. Once it get selected, it displays a text field and calendar button instead of just a text field.

Then, I went to trace the code and found productOptionType.loadStepTwo() in `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml`, which seems related to this enhancement.

But what is the best way/technique to modify that method of object literal without touching the original file and not have problems with magento core updates? Appreciate.

```
var productOptionType = {
templateSyntax : /(^|.|\r|\n)({{(\w+)}})/,
loadStepTwo : function(event){
    var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'select'));

    var group = '';
    var previousGroupElm = $(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', '_previous_group'));

    switch(element.getValue()){
        case 'field':
        case 'area':
            template = OptionTemplateText;
            group = 'text';
            break;
        case 'file':
            template = OptionTemplateFile;
            group = 'file';
            break;
        case 'drop_down':
        case 'radio':
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'multiple':
            template = OptionTemplateSelect;
            group = 'select';
            break;
        case 'date':
        case 'date_time':
        case 'time':
            template = OptionTemplateDate;
            group = 'date';
            break;
        default:
            template = '';
            group = 'unknown';
            break;
    }

    if (previousGroupElm.getValue() != group) {
        if ($(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue())) {
            formElm = $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).descendants();
            formElm.each(function(elm){
                if (elm.tagName == 'input' || elm.tagName == 'select') {
                    elm.name = '__delete__'+elm.readAttribute('name');
                }
            });

            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).addClassName('no-display');
            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).addClassName('ignore-validate');
            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).hide();
        }

        previousGroupElm.value = group;

        if ($(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group)) {
            formElm = $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).descendants();
            formElm.each(function(elm){
                if (elm.match('input') || elm.match('select')) {
                    elm.name = elm.readAttribute('name').sub('__delete__', '');
                }
            });
            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).removeClassName('no-display');
            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).removeClassName('ignore-validate');
            $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).show();

        } else {
            template = '<div id="'+element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group+'" class="grid tier form-list">'+template+'</div><div id="'+element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group+'_advice"></div';
            this.secondTemplate = new Template(template, this.templateSyntax);

            data = {};
            if (!data.option_id) {
                data = {};
                data.option_id = $(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', '_id')).getValue();
            }

            Element.insert(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', ''), {'after':this.secondTemplate.evaluate(data)});

            switch(element.getValue()){
                case 'drop_down':
                case 'radio':
                case 'checkbox':
                case 'multiple':
                    selectOptionType.bindAddButton();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
},
addDataToValues : function(data){

    switch(data.type){
        case 'field':
        case 'area':
            template = OptionTemplateText;
            group = 'text';
            break;
        case 'file':
            template = OptionTemplateFile;
            group = 'file';
            break;
        case 'drop_down':
        case 'radio':
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'multiple':
            template = OptionTemplateSelect;
            group = 'select';
            break;
        case 'date':
        case 'date_time':
        case 'time':
            template = OptionTemplateDate;
            group = 'date';
            break;
    }

    $('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.id+'_previous_group').value = group;

    template = '<div id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_{{id}}_type_'+group+'" class="grid tier form-list">'+template+'</div><div id="<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_{{id}}_type_'+group+'_advice"></div>';

    this.secondTemplate = new Template(template, this.templateSyntax);

    Element.insert($('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.option_id), {'after':this.secondTemplate.evaluate(data)});

    if (data.checkboxScopePrice) {
        //set disabled
        if ($('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.option_id+'_price') && data.scopePriceDisabled) {
            $('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.option_id+'_price').disable();
            $('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.option_id+'_price_type').disable();
        }
    }

    switch(data.type){
        case 'drop_down':
        case 'radio':
        case 'checkbox':
        case 'multiple':
            data.optionValues.each(function(value) {
                selectOptionType.add(value);
            });
            selectOptionType.bindAddButton();
            break;
    }

    if (data.price_type) {
        $A($('<?php echo $this->getFieldId() ?>_'+data.option_id+'_price_type').options).each(function(option){
            if (option.value==data.price_type) option.selected = true;
        });
    }

},
bindSelectInputType : function(){
    var types = $$('.select-product-option-type');
    for(var i=0;i<types.length;i++){
        if(!$(types[i]).binded){
            $(types[i]).binded = true;
            Event.observe(types[i], 'change', function(event){
                productOptionType.loadStepTwo(event);
            });
        }
    }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way I could think of is to replace the existing method. So, in case there is a core updates for that particular method, only new option 'radio_button' would missed out the updates.

Hereby attached the following code, and please feel free to share your view.

```
if(typeof productOptionType !== 'undefined')
{
    // replace existing method productOptionType.loadStepTwo
    productOptionType.loadStepTwo = (function() {
        var cached_function = productOptionType.loadStepTwo;

        return function() {
            var element = $(Event.findElement(event, 'select'));

            var group = '';
            var previousGroupElm = $(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', '_previous_group'));

            switch(element.getValue()){
                case 'radio_date':
                    template = OptionTemplateSelect;
                    group = 'select';
                    break;
                default:
                    // use magento core logic
                    return cached_function.apply(this, arguments); 
            }

            // same logic as magento core v1.9.1.1
            if (previousGroupElm.getValue() != group) {
                if ($(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue())) {
                    formElm = $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).descendants();
                    formElm.each(function(elm){
                        if (elm.tagName == 'input' || elm.tagName == 'select') {
                            elm.name = '__delete__'+elm.readAttribute('name');
                        }
                    });

                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).addClassName('no-display');
                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).addClassName('ignore-validate');
                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+previousGroupElm.getValue()).hide();
                }

                previousGroupElm.value = group;

                if ($(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group)) {
                    formElm = $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).descendants();
                    formElm.each(function(elm){
                        if (elm.match('input') || elm.match('select')) {
                            elm.name = elm.readAttribute('name').sub('__delete__', '');
                        }
                    });
                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).removeClassName('no-display');
                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).removeClassName('ignore-validate');
                    $(element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group).show();

                } else {
                    template = '<div id="'+element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group+'" class="grid tier form-list">'+template+'</div><div id="'+element.readAttribute('id')+'_'+group+'_advice"></div';
                    this.secondTemplate = new Template(template, this.templateSyntax);

                    data = {};
                    if (!data.option_id) {
                        data = {};
                        data.option_id = $(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', '_id')).getValue();
                    }

                    Element.insert(element.readAttribute('id').sub('_type', ''), {'after':this.secondTemplate.evaluate(data)});

                    switch(element.getValue()){
                        case 'radio_date': 
                            selectOptionType.bindAddButton();
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }());
}
```